# Spring get username after login failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to generate url which will resend account activation token after login failure (when account is disabled).

I have CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler:

```
  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
  AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
    setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=true");
    super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);
    String errorMessage = messages.getMessage("message.badCredentials", null, locale);

    if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User is disabled")) {
      errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.disabled", null, locale);
    } else if (exception.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User account has expired")) {
      errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale);
    }

    request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, errorMessage);
  }
```

I need it only in view (jsp), so I will be happy if there is way to get it in view from for example sth like `${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_ATTEMPT.username}` but if there is no option - how to send it from `onAuthenticationFailure` to model?

Answer (score 0):

First we create a customized authenticationProvider class.

```
@Component("authenticationProvider")
public class DisabledLoginAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    @Override
    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
          throws AuthenticationException {

      try {

        Authentication auth = super.authenticate(authentication);

        //if reach here, means login success, else an exception will be thrown
        //reset the user_attempts

        return auth;

      } catch (DisabledException e){

        //this user is disabled!
        String error = "";

   //this will db to check the no of attempts
            UserAttempts userAttempts = 
                        userDetailsDao.getUserAttempts(authentication.getName());

               if(userAttempts!=null){
            Date lastAttempts = userAttempts.getLastModified();
            error = "User account is locked! <br><br>Username : " 
                           + authentication.getName() + "<br>Last Attempts : " + lastAttempts;
        }else{
            error = e.getMessage();
        }

      throw new LockedException(error);
    }

    }

}
```

Then inside your Security xml attach your customized authenticationProvider.

```
<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**The first step**

to add spring security in your application is to create Spring Security Java Configuration
for example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/list")
                .access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')")
                .antMatchers("/newuser/**", "/delete-user-*").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").antMatchers("/edit-user-*")
                .access("hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('DBA')").and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("ssoId").passwordParameter("password").and()
                .rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me").tokenRepository(tokenRepository)
                .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices getPersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices() {
        PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices tokenBasedservice = new PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices(
                "remember-me", userDetailsService, tokenRepository);
        return tokenBasedservice;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationTrustResolver getAuthenticationTrustResolver() {
        return new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();
    }

}
```

**The second step**

implementation of PersistentTokenRepository
example:

```
@Repository("tokenRepositoryDao")
@Transactional
public class HibernateTokenRepositoryImpl extends AbstractDao<String, PersistentLogin>
        implements PersistentTokenRepository {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateTokenRepositoryImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void createNewToken(PersistentRememberMeToken token) {
        logger.info("Creating Token for user : {}", token.getUsername());
        PersistentLogin persistentLogin = new PersistentLogin();
        persistentLogin.setUsername(token.getUsername());
        persistentLogin.setSeries(token.getSeries());
        persistentLogin.setToken(token.getTokenValue());
        persistentLogin.setLast_used(token.getDate());
        persist(persistentLogin);

    }

    @Override
    public PersistentRememberMeToken getTokenForSeries(String seriesId) {
        logger.info("Fetch Token if any for seriesId : {}", seriesId);
        try {
            Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq("series", seriesId));
            PersistentLogin persistentLogin = (PersistentLogin) crit.uniqueResult();

            return new PersistentRememberMeToken(persistentLogin.getUsername(), persistentLogin.getSeries(),
                    persistentLogin.getToken(), persistentLogin.getLast_used());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Token not found...");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUserTokens(String username) {
        logger.info("Removing Token if any for user : {}", username);
        Criteria crit = createEntityCriteria();
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        PersistentLogin persistentLogin = (PersistentLogin) crit.uniqueResult();
        if (persistentLogin != null) {
            logger.info("rememberMe was selected");
            delete(persistentLogin);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void updateToken(String seriesId, String tokenValue, Date lastUsed) {
        logger.info("Updating Token for seriesId : {}", seriesId);
        PersistentLogin persistentLogin = getByKey(seriesId);
        persistentLogin.setToken(tokenValue);
        persistentLogin.setLast_used(lastUsed);
        update(persistentLogin);
    }

}
```

Above implementation uses an Entity [PersistentLogin] mapped to persistent_logins table, shown below is the entity itself.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSISTENT_LOGINS")
public class PersistentLogin implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String series;

    @Column(name="USERNAME", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="TOKEN", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String token;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date last_used;

    public String getSeries() {
        return series;
    }

    public void setSeries(String series) {
        this.series = series;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public Date getLast_used() {
        return last_used;
    }

    public void setLast_used(Date last_used) {
        this.last_used = last_used;
    }


}
```

The UserDetailsService implementation, used in Security configuration:

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomUserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String ssoId)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findBySSO(ssoId);
        logger.info("User : {}", user);
        if(user==null){
            logger.info("User not found");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found");
        }
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getSsoId(), user.getPassword(), 
                 true, true, true, true, getGrantedAuthorities(user));
    }


    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        for(UserProfile userProfile : user.getUserProfiles()){
            logger.info("UserProfile : {}", userProfile);
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+userProfile.getType()));
        }
        logger.info("authorities : {}", authorities);
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

**Last step**
register the springSecurityFilter with application war:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for 'remember me' implementation but I have already done it :)